Cannot get same test output on open liberty getting started tutorial
I'm doing the "guide-maven-intro" tutorial on the open liberty website here:
maven-intro tutorial
And I'm trying to get the same output as  you see in this link for the test output.
However, I'm not getting that, i'm getting this:
 Application ServletSample started in 0.197 seconds..
[INFO] Running integration tests...
[INFO] Integration tests finished.
[INFO] 
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.

[INFO] Running unit tests...
[INFO] Rendering content with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.3 skin.
[INFO] Unit tests finished.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Running integration tests...
[INFO] Integration tests finished.
[INFO] 
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.

As you can see, it doesn't show the results of the tests: Pass, Fail, etc, like the output of running mvn liberty:dev does in the tutorial.
I changed the compiler source and target in the pom.xml from 11 to 17. This is the only change I made.
Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or things have changed since tutorial was written?

I can't think of what might have gone wrong.  Since it's just a sample, I could take a look if you'd run with mvn -X liberty:dev and capture the logs.  Just be sure to redirect the logs to a file outside of the main project directory, or dev mode may end up watching the log file and reacting to changes.

Another quick question: What version of mvn are you using?

@ScottKurz I'm running maven v3.9.7. Thanks for taking a look. I will do what you told me to do when I get home from work, in another 9 hours or so. Thanks

Are you sure that you run that from the finish directory not start? As start has empty tests :-)

@ScottKurz I have fixed this issue, but It was an issue that I must have created somehow because I deleted the project and recloned it and started again, but this time cutting and pasting EndpointIT.java and the pom.xml file instead of handtyping it out. The only things I changed in this pom.xml this time was the compiler source and target to 17, and the liberty-maven-plugin to 3.10.3 from 3.10.2. It now works including putting a different greeting string in to fail the test. Thanks.

Hi @Gas thanks for responding. I was actually in the start directory, but I must have made some error typing out the pom.xml. I have learned my lesson now to at least cut and paste first when I'm trying to get new technology to work and then focus on learning by doing after that. Cheers.
